# CSS: -ms-filter not working on IE in angular 4

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer, angular2-template

Filters are not working in IE browser using angular 4.
Here my code for css code:

```
.style{-ms-filter: grayscale(50%); -ms-filter: brightness(70%);}
```

Comment: IE 8 and above version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The modern definition of css `filter` doesn't work in IE8. IE8 does have the older, proprietary MS filters, but those are not the same.
2. You can't have 2 properties to a selector a row with the same name. That's not how CSS works. In this case, the second `-ms-filter` will override the first one, so that only `brightness(70%)` is used.
   The solution, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), is to use commas to separate multiple values.

Aside from that, apparently neither the old MS versions nor the newer standard versions are supported by IE10 and IE11, so you're out of luck in any version.

You can use

```css
.style {filter:gray}
```

in IE8 to set the gray scale to 100%, but I haven't found any equivalent for `brightness`, sorry.